# CUDA 9 shfl vs. shfl_sync

Tags: cuda

Since CUDA 9 the shfl instructions are deprecated and should be replaced by shfl_sync.

But how should i replace them, when they behave differently?

Code Example:

```
__global__
static void shflTest(){
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    float value = tid + 0.1f;
    int* ivalue = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&value);

    //use the integer shfl
    int ix = __shfl(ivalue[0],5,32);
    int iy = __shfl_sync(ivalue[0],5,32);

    float x = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&ix)[0];
    float y = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&iy)[0];

    if(tid == 0){
        printf("shfl tmp %d %d\n",ix,iy);
        printf("shfl final %f %f\n",x,y);
    }
}

int main()
{
    shflTest<<<1,32>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
shfl tmp 1084437299 5
shfl final 5.100000 0.000000
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you read the CUDA 9RC programming guide (section B.15), installed with your copy of CUDA 9RC, you will see that the new `__shfl_sync()` function has an additional `mask` parameter which you are not accounting for:

CUDA 8:

```
int __shfl(int var, int srcLane, int width=warpSize);
```

CUDA 9:

```
T __shfl_sync(unsigned mask, T var, int srcLane, int width=warpSize);
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The expectation for this mask parameter is also indicated:

> The new *_sync shfl intrinsics take in a mask indicating the threads participating in the
>   call. A bit, representing the thread's lane id, must be set for each participating thread to
>   ensure they are properly converged before the intrinsic is executed by the hardware. All
>   non-exited threads named in mask must execute the same intrinsic with the same mask,
>   or the result is undefined.

Therefore, if we modify your code to conform with this, we get the expected result:

```
$ cat t419.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__
static void shflTest(int lid){
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    float value = tid + 0.1f;
    int* ivalue = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&value);

    //use the integer shfl
    int ix = __shfl(ivalue[0],5,32);
    int iy = __shfl_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, ivalue[0],5,32);

    float x = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&ix)[0];
    float y = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&iy)[0];

    if(tid == lid){
        printf("shfl tmp %d %d\n",ix,iy);
        printf("shfl final %f %f\n",x,y);
    }
}

int main()
{
    shflTest<<<1,32>>>(0);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t419 t419.cu
t419.cu(10): warning: function "__shfl(int, int, int)"
/usr/local/cuda/bin/..//include/sm_30_intrinsics.hpp(152): here was declared deprecated ("__shfl() is deprecated in favor of __shfl_sync() and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-declarations to suppress this warning).")

$ cuda-memcheck ./t419
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
shfl tmp 1084437299 1084437299
shfl final 5.100000 5.100000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Is it save to replace all `shfl_xx(...)` with `shfl_xx_sync(0xFFFFFFFF,...)` even when the width is not 32?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense to me.  Do you know how the width parameter works?

Comment: The width parameter does some sort of 'modulo' operation on the target lane id of a shuffle. So a `shfl(tid,0,16)` should give 0 for the first 16 threads and 16 for the last 16 threads. So my guess is that it does something like this: `actualTargetLaneId = targetLaneId % width + targetLaneId / width * width`

Comment: Yes, the width parameter breaks the full warp width (32 lanes) into a set of equal-sized power-of-2 subgroups, e.g. 4 groups of 8, or 8 groups of 4.  Within each subgroup, the same shuffle operation takes place, modulo the group width.  So if you have 4 groups of 8, but you want the shuffle operation to be performed in each of the 4 groups of 8, then you should still pass a mask parameter of `0xFFFFFFFF`.  In short, the mask parameter and the width parameter are mostly orthogonal to each other.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I understand everything now. I replaced all shfl instructions with shfl_sync and my code still works. By the way the compiler seems to ignore the `mask` parameter completely for non volta architectures. I tested it by using the mask `0x0` for all shfl instructions and it still works :). I mean this kinda makes sense because all threads in a warp are guaranteed to execute the same instruction.

Comment: Any idea why you get a warning from sm_30_intrinsics.hpp when you are compiling for sm_61?

Comment: Because I have both `__shfl` and `__shfl_sync` in the code, and `__shfl` is deprecated, for all architectures.  Since `__shfl` is available from sm_30 forward, the `sm_30_intrinsics.hpp` is included (by `nvcc`) to provide the prototype for all architectures.