# Some intrinsics named with `_sync()` appended in CUDA 9; semantics same?

Tags: cuda, ptx, gpu-warp

In CUDA 9, nVIDIA seems to have this new notion of "cooperative groups"; and for some reason not entirely clear to me, `__ballot()` is now (= CUDA 9) deprecated in favor of `__ballot_sync()`. Is that an alias or have the semantics changed?

... similar question for other builtins which now have `__sync()` added to their names.

Comment: no, the semantics are different.  Providing a complete answer strikes me as a large effort, especially considering there is considerable new documentation in the CUDA 9 programming guide that covers various aspects of this.  On the surface of it, this seems like a very broad question.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345811/cuda-9-shfl-vs-shfl-sync) is an example of a related, focused question that can be answered in a reasonable space (albeit fairly evident if you just read the documentation).

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I guess I should have asked "...semantics same when passing the active mask?" or "when passing the all-ones mask?"

Comment: even then the semantics are different if you're on a volta processor vs. some other processor.  see the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467011/thread-synchronization-with-syncwarp).  Describing all the syntactical differences could dive into a tutorial on volta thread independence, cooperative groups, and perhaps other topics.  They are not just an alias, even with a specific mask.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: The combination of your comments is an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No the semantics are not the same.  The function calls themselves are different, one is not an alias for another, new functionality has been exposed, and the implementation behavior is now different between Volta architecture and previous architectures.

First of all, to set the ground work, it's necessary to be cognizant of the fact that Volta [introduced the possibility](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#application-compatibility) for [**independent thread scheduling**](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#independent-thread-scheduling-7-x), by introducing a per-thread program counter and other changes.  As a result of this, it's possible for Volta to behave in a non-warp-synchronous behavior for extended periods of time, and during periods of execution when previous architectures might still be warp-synchronous.

Most of the warp intrinsics work by only delivering expected results for threads that are actually participating (i.e. are actually active for the issue of that instruction, in that cycle).  The programmer can now be explicit about which threads are expected to participate, via the new `mask` parameter.    However there are some requirements, in particular  on Pascal and previous architectures.  From [the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#independent-thread-scheduling-7-x):

> Note, however, that for Pascal and earlier architectures, all threads in `mask` must execute the same warp intrinsic instruction in convergence, and the union of all values in mask must be equal to the warp's active mask.

On Volta, however, the warp execution engine will bring about the necessary synchronization/participation amongst the indicated threads in the mask, in order to make the desired/indicated operation valid (assuming the appropriate `_sync` version of the instrinsic is used).  To be clear, the warp execution engine will reconverge threads that are diverged on volta in order to match the mask, however it will not overcome programmer induced errors such as preventing a thread from participating in a `_sync()` intrinsic via conditional statements.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345811/cuda-9-shfl-vs-shfl-sync) related question discusses the `mask` parameter.  This answer is not intended to address all possible questions that may arise from independent thread scheduling and the impact on warp level intrinsics.  For that, I encourage reading of the programming guide.