# Thread synchronization with syncwarp

Tags: cuda

Apart from the `__syncthreads()` function(s) which synchronizes the warps within a thread block, theres another function called `__syncwarp()`. What exactly does this function do?

The [cuda programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html) says,

> will cause the executing thread to wait until all warp lanes named in mask have executed a __syncwarp() (with the same mask) before resuming execution. All non-exited threads named in mask must execute a corresponding __syncwarp() with the same mask, or the result is undefined.
>
> Executing __syncwarp() guarantees memory ordering among threads participating in the barrier. Thus, threads within a warp that wish to communicate via memory can store to memory, execute __syncwarp(), and then safely read values stored by other threads in the warp.

So does this mean that this function ensures synchronization in threads within a warp that is included by the mask? If so, do we need such synchronization within the threads in the same warp since they all are ensured to be executed in lockstep?

Comment: threads in a warp are *not* ensured to be executed in lockstep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature is available on CUDA 9 and yes it synchronizes all threads within a warp and useful for divergent warps. This is useful for Volta architecture in which threads within a warp can be scheduled separately.